# In Developer Story, Jan..Sep counts as only 8 months

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

**Alleged bug:**
The Developer Story counts Jan..Sep as only 8 months.

**Expected:**
Count the stated months in their entirety; the stated months should implicitly be interpreted as "first day of the starting month" and "last day of ending month".

In [my Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/torbengb), my latest job runs from January one year to September of another year - the exact dates are from 2010-01-01 until 2016-09-30 so obviously I expect that to be counted as (6 years and) 9 months. This is how other major job profile websites ([[1]](https://www.linkedin.com/in/torbengb),[[2]](https://www.xing.com/profile/Torben_GundtofteBruun)) calculate it, and it seems intuitive on the premise that if I claim to have worked until September, that means I worked *for a significant part of* September.

The current situation is simply not accurate. My jobs are almost always from the first of a month to the last of a month, so the current solution consistently cheats me of a month.

**Proposed solution:**
Either fully include any listed month in the calculation, or allow (or require?) a full date for the most accurate calculation.

Comment: It's intuitive in one sense, but not in another. Suppose you have 2 jobs in a year - one January to mid-June and the other mid-June to the end of December. That would show 13 months in one year. If you had more jobs, you could end up with even more total months... I think it's reasonable that *on average*, a January-September job lasts 8 months. (Sometimes it will last nearly 9; sometimes it will last only just more than 7... but the average would be 8.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, it would be _accurate_ if it showed that you worked 13 months that year because you did in fact have _two_ jobs in June. Makes perfect sense to me. A resolution that satisfies both of us could be if the Story let us add the day of the month as well.

Comment: But you didn't actually work for 13 months of the year (you weren't working the *whole* of June in both jobs), so no, it wouldn't be accurate. I agree that adding the day would allow more accuracy.

Comment: @JonSkeet The same is true in the other direction: A job from January 1st to June 30th and another job from July 1st to December 31st would count as 10 months total.

Comment: @Stijn: Indeed. Basically, there will always be room for inaccuracy in this model, but it should average out correctly - whereas the proposed scheme would average to over-statement.

Comment: The proposed scheme is based on counting whole months, based on the premise that if I claim to have worked until September, that means I worked _for a significant part of_ September. The current situation is simply not accurate. And for what it's worth, my kind of job almost always is from the first of a month to the last of a month, so the current solution will _consistently_ cheat me of a month ... it won't ever average out.

Comment: It may not average out *for you*, but that's not the same as saying that your proposed fix will make it more accurate *on average*. The "significant part of" aspect is pretty vague, IMO. If I work from (say) September 17th to October 13th, does that mean I haven't worked a "significant" part of either month? (It's less than half, after all...) So that means that's "worth" 0 months? Basically, there will always be "winners" and "losers" with any scheme like this, but I'd be nervous of anything that ended up double-counting months.

Comment: One possible fix would be to use multiple consecutive positions to work things out - if the same month occurs as both the end of one position and the start of another, then only count it in one of the roles (either). But it shouldn't count in both.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't agree with you, but I think we can agree that if an accurate average is as important as you seem to suggest, then the system needs more precision than it presently has. At any rate, it's downright ridiculous that it calculates differently than the major career portals out there.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun: I'd say it's ridiculous that the major career portals could easily show you working 20 months in a year, but there we go. It's certainly not something that's going to bother me - if an employer really cares about "6 years 7 months" vs "6 years 8 months" then I'm unlikely to be interested in them...

Comment: @Jon you are diverting into an irrelevant path. That doesn't change the fact that the count is plain wrong.

Comment: And it would be plain wrong for other people if it followed the "include all" algorithm you endorse.

Comment: Are you always this difficult to talk to? Read my post, in particular the very last sentence. I am submitting a bug about inaccuracy and request accuracy. Nothing wrong in that. End of (tiresome) discussion.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. We're looking at how we are calculating it and possible ways to fix it.

Comment: wonder if picking jobs _from the last of a month to the first of a month_ would be an acceptable workaround :)

Comment: I will not consider taking the developer story seriously if that's not fixed. IMHO it's ridiculous. It's particularly problematic for short internships.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't agree with the argument "all of these resumes may be wrong but its ok because the wrongness averages out".

Comment: @nhouser9: It's not ideal, but it's surely better than "an equal number of CVs are wrong in a different direction and the wrongness *doesn't* average out". It's more likely that the wrongness averages out *within a single CV*, IMO. Would you really be happy with a system which could easily claim you worked more than 12 months in a year? I wouldn't, personally.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think it should match what other job search sites are doing, especially because it is important right now to get people to "buy in" to the developer story idea.

Comment: @nhouser9: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. Stack Overflow didn't get to where it is by following other sites' broken models...