# Position shows as '3 years, 12 months' instead of '4 years'

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

This is shown on my developer story. I am close to 4 years here; so I think it should either show 3 years 11 months or 4 years.

> [image: screenshot of developer story]

Comment: Might be related: [In Developer Story, Jan..Sep counts as only 8 months](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336050/in-developer-story-jan-sep-counts-as-only-8-months)

Comment: @Stijn very related imo :D

Comment: Thanks for reporting it, we'll take a look at it shortly.

Comment: both '3 years, 12 months' and '4 years' are wrong, position apparently should show _'2 years, 24 months'_ (@Kit please keep this in mind, it is important to get things right here)

Comment: This is just an ingenious ploy to get some free publicity from a feature article on http://thedailywtf.com

Comment: 3 years, 12 months is correct since the 4th year is a leap year - it has 13 months.

Comment: @rmaddy What? Leap... month?

Comment: @Link That was a joke.

Comment: Hopefully it won't be confused further by the leap second at December 31, 2016

Comment: What about fractional years? 3.95 years =)

Comment: This means that I'm 21, and then just a bunch of months

Comment: I think the careers system was finally switched over to the Gregorian calendar in September.

Comment: Either display as **3 Years, 11+ Months** or **3 Years, 11 Months, 30 Days**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! This will be fixed with our next production build :).